# Не работает Dialog для проверки лицензии, в андроид приложении

Tags: java, android

Всем добрый день. Мне очень нужна помощь в следующем вопросе. Я пытаюсь добавить в свое приложение проверку лицензии Google Play, нашел подробную инструкцию [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324963/how-can-i-implement-google-play-licensing-for-an-android-app), как я понял этот код должен выводить диалоговое окно с вариантами выбора, но я никак не могу понять почему он не работает. Приложение крашится на вызове docheck(); после разметки.
Подскажите что я делаю не так?! Спасибо!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Handler mHandler;
private LicenseChecker mChecker;
private LicenseCheckerCallback mLicenseCheckerCallback;
boolean licensed;
boolean checkingLicense;
boolean didCheck;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

docheck();

    String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    Log.i("Device Id", deviceId);  //AN EXAMPLE OF LOGGING THAT YOU SHOULD BE DOING :)

    mHandler = new Handler();
    mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();
    mChecker = new LicenseChecker(this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this, new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)), BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);

}

private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "MIIBI";
private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] {82,17,06,38,05,94,59,05,21,62,37,48,79,77,03,54,46,85,48,34};


private void doCheck() {

    didCheck = false;
    checkingLicense = true;
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);

}


private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {

    @Override
    public void allow(int reason) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }
        Log.i("License","Accepted!");

        //You can do other things here, like saving the licensed status to a
        //SharedPreference so the app only has to check the license once.

        licensed = true;
        checkingLicense = false;
        didCheck = true;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void dontAllow(int reason) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }
        Log.i("License","Denied!");
        Log.i("License","Reason for denial: "+reason);

        //You can do other things here, like saving the licensed status to a
        //SharedPreference so the app only has to check the license once.

        licensed = false;
        checkingLicense = false;
        didCheck = true;

        showDialog(0);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void applicationError(int reason) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("License", "Error: " + reason);
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }
        licensed = true;
        checkingLicense = false;
        didCheck = false;

        showDialog(0);
    }


}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // We have only one dialog.
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("UNLICENSED APPLICATION DIALOG TITLE")
            .setMessage("This application is not licensed, please buy it from the play store.")
            .setPositiveButton("Buy", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                            "http://market.android.com/details?id=" + getPackageName()));
                    startActivity(marketIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setNeutralButton("Re-Check", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    doCheck();
                }
            })

            .setCancelable(false)
            .setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener(){
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    Log.i("License", "Key Listener");
                    finish();
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .create();

}
```

}

Comment: Код, кажестя или не полный или содержит методы из разных классов. Т.е. сориентироваться в нём сложно. Последний метод выглядит как переопределение метода в DialogFragment... Если последнее не верно, то вам надо где-то `show()` вызвать для созданного диалога

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вы правы! я только что вспомнил про debug и как оказалось что весь код после разметки не активен, автор этого кода написал что для проверки необходимо вызывать docheck();  , но так приложение вообще крашится.

Comment: Если что-то крашится и вы хотите чтобы кто-то вам помог решить эту проблему - надо обновить вопрос с указанием что вы дополнили в коде и на какой строке крашится и с какой ошибкой и приложить логи оной.